# alloc init does not increase retain count

Tags: iphone

Basically if I do (not that I want to do this, just i'm trying to understand)

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

array should now be having a retain count of 3 right?

But somehow with me it doesn't

Comment: Please bear in mind that using `[x retainCount];` isn't a reliable technique. With that said, answers below are right, you're just leaking the first two arrays you alloc'ed.

Answer (score 4):

You have allocated three different `NSMutableArray`s, each one with a retain count of 1.

The first two of them are leaked.

Comment: Ok clear. they all reserve memory but as the 2nd overwrites the first and the the 3th overwrites the 2nd I'm left with 2 memory reservations which I have no way to access to only the 3th one stays usable to me.

Comment: yes, it is exactly like that. pointers are overwritten, so memory is still reserved, but unreachable. it would be different if `array` were a `retain` property and you did: `self.array = ...`; in this case, no memory leaks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with self.array.. Could you give me an example?

Comment: That was just an example about a different way of managing memory (i.e., using class properties). If you are interested in more detail, have a look at this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Each time your creating a new array with its retain counter.
To increase retain counter, you would have to do something like:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array retain];
[array retain];
```

Comment: Yep this I know. Was just not sure if alloc init would create a new instance or just increase the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
nothing -/->    [array1 - count=1]   (memory leak)
nothing -/->    [array2 - count=1]   (memory leak)
array   --->    [array3 - count=1]
```

Answer (score -1):

No, it won't. Actually, the three arrays are not same. All would have different references.

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array retain];
```

This will increase the retain count.

Comment: This will have a retainCount of 2, since alloc init will increase the count to 1